# How to label xAxis with series data using Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I'm newbie to highchart and I've got a demo for [polar chart using highcharts](https://jsfiddle.net/h1ta36xb/7/)

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'area'
    },

    accessibility: {
        description: 'ASDFR'
    },

    title: {
        text: '',
        x: -120
    },

    pane: {
        size: '100%',
        startAngle:-42
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['ATT', 'TEC', 'TAC', 'DEF', 'CRE'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0,
        labels:{
            formatter: function(){
            return this.value + '???' 
          }
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name} <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b></span>'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        layout: 'vertical'
    },

    series: [{
        name: '',
        data: [73, 80, 80, 54, 92],
        
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    layout: 'horizontal'
                },
                pane: {
                    size: '70%'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

How can I show the value of the series right in the xAxis label e.g  ATT 73, TEC 80, TAC 80...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the associated value through series data. Example:

```
    xAxis: {
        ...,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.value + ' ' + this.chart.series[0].yData[this.pos];
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pyohzk8c/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: thanks a lot. I didnt know this.pos existing :D